# Switching a chrome extension from Free to a Subscription fee, what happens to users who got the extension for free?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm thinking about changing my chrome extension from Free to Subscription based. I currently have 13,000 users on my chrome extension so I'd like to start charging $0.99/month for it.

What happens to the users who got the extension for free? Do they also have to pay the monthly fee? How does Google ask them to pay if they are already using it?

Also, for those who have switched like this before, what percentage of users ended up paying for the extension?

Comment: they remain same they can not be charged new user will be charge for extension

Comment: if you want to give pop them old user if you used any own link in extension